# Как можно передать данние с сервера

Tags: javascript, html

**Помогите решить проблему с отрисовкой меток на карте. Я получаю latitude и longitude с сервера, как мне передать их в функцию initMap чтоб отрисовать на карте?**

Вот мой код

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

const test = {
  query: 'restaurant',
  radius: 100000,
  lat: 60,
  lng: 56,
}


let a = 'http://198.199.125.240:8888/search'

// Щоб вивести на сторінці
async function getUsers(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(test),
  })

  let data = await response.json()
  
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getUsers(a)
})


// GOOGLE API
function initMap() {

  const element = document.querySelector('.map')

  const options = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 49.842957, lng: 24.031111 },
  }

  const myMap = new google.maps.Map(element, options)
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Google API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn">POST/GEO</button>
    <div class="map"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAjFpHVA975VUp9CROB_cguglhjVOc9J00&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      async
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/178576)?

Comment: нет, я впервые, знаете как помочь?

Comment: response это то, что вернул вам ```fetch```. ```getUsers``` - вам ничего не возвращает, пусть она вернет ```response```. Тогда в``` initMap``` ```await getUsers()```

Comment: в ``` initMap``` let data = await response.json()

Comment: я немного запутался, можешь показать,и не подскажешь еще как тогда сделать по кнопке визов?

Comment: @WalkMess не работает

Comment: Ну так data - это результат функции, которая вернёт промис. Я просто, как пример представил let data